# DAX - Running totals filter by year

Tags: powerbi, dax

I've created a formula to calculate running totals and it works

```
    Acumulado =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'Consulta 2016'[Valor Empréstimo] );
    FILTER (
        ALL ( 'Consulta 2016' );
        'Consulta 2016'[Data de Criação] <= MAX ( 'Consulta 2016'[Data de Criação] )
    )
)
```

But I need to change this to filter for a specific year. Tried a few different things and nothing worked, like

```
Acumulado =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'Consulta 2016'[Valor Empréstimo] );
    FILTER (
        ALL ( 'Consulta 2016' );
        'Consulta 2016'[Data de Criação].YEAR < 2018
            <= MAX ( 'Consulta 2016'[Data de Criação] )
    )
)
```

Any help would be wellcome.

Comment: In what way did the things you've tried not work? errors, wrong results, something else?

Comment: The code I tried as a solution is the second one and it throws a "Unexpected expression Year" error.

Comment: ALL ( 'Consulta 2016' ) removes all filters on your date. Remove it and try with just year filter as you did.  'Consulta 2016'[Data de Criação].YEAR < 2018

Comment: I advise you to  edit your question: translate the spanish  to english so people might easier understand what you are trying to do

Comment: @Henrov the portuguese words are query and field names. ,One can understand the formula as it is.

Comment: Portugese.. Sorry.. Didn't mean to be annoying or so. 'Data*' are probably date fields then?

Comment: @Henrov I apologize if I sounded a bit harsh and thank you for taking the time to review the question. Yes, Data is a datetime field.

Answer (score 0):

The `All()`statement removes all filters. I think this is what you are looking for:

This is < 2018:

```
Acumulado =
CALCULATE(
    SUM('Consulta 2016'[Valor Empréstimo] );
        'Consulta 2016'[Data de Criação].YEAR < 2018)
```

This is both < 2018 and <= Max

```
Acumulado =
CALCULATE(
    SUM('Consulta 2016'[Valor Empréstimo] );
        'Consulta 2016'[Data de Criação].YEAR < 2018 &&
        'Consulta 2016'[Data de Criação].YEAR <= MAX ('Consulta 2016'[Data de Criação]))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer but that doesn't work either. This formula sums the value for all the dates under 2018, but what I need is a running total, which is what I did in the first formula, but for a specific year (which is what I need to do). Thanks again brother.